# Can a nontrivial abelian group have trivial Pontryagin dual?

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory, pontrjagin-duality

Let $A$ be an abelian group, and suppose $$\mathrm{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})=0.$$

Does it follow that $A=0$?

This is true for $A$ finitely-generated, any subgroup of any product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, any $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, among others. But is it true for an *arbitrary* abelian group?

Comment: There's an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829544/the-dual-for-abelian-group-on-q-z

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829544/the-dual-for-abelian-group-on-q-z

Comment: Every abelian group embeds in a divisible abelian group, which embeds in a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$. So what you have observed already answers the question.